# Paste Special not working for Paste Values

Tags: copy-paste

I'm getting a compile error and Syntax error

I have tried both

```
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet3")
```

1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
   `lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
   'Offset property moves down 1 row
   `lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`
3. Copy & Paste Values
   `wsCopy.Range("A4:BL" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
   wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

To paste the value only without the paste value I'm getting all the formulas copied I only want the values.

Comment: If found the error.   No Answer needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste Values
  wsCopy.Range("A4:BL" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues